# How to find an Agar.io Ogar private server?

Tags: agar.io

I want to play an Agar.io private server made with the Ogar software, but when I search online it comes up with disrelated content. Is there any way to filter out Ogar servers from normal Agar.io private servers?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=agario+private+server+-ogar&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: You can put a minus sign before a word to exclude results containing that word from your search.

Answer (score 4):

You can set up your own Ogar server quite easily, see: https://github.com/OgarProject/Ogar

> If you are on Windows, you can download the latest binary build of Ogar from [this page](http://dl.ogarproject.com/). The binary is the easiest way to get started running an Ogar server. If you'd like to tinker with the source code, you can follow the instructions below (and slightly modify them) to run the source on Windows.
>
> As Ogar is written in Node.js, you must have Node.js and its "ws" module installed to use it (unless you are using the Windows binary). You can usually download Node using your distribution's package manager (for *nix-like systems), or from [the Node website](http://nodejs.org/). To install the "ws" module that is required, open up your system command line (cmd for windows, terminal for mac) and type "npm install ws". If you are on Linux, you can use the install script which would also automatically install node.js and ws.
>
> - https://github.com/OgarProject/Ogar#obtaining-and-using

if you'd like to set up your own server, ask in the comments and I can elaborate on how to do so using Ogar.

---

Once you've set up your own server, you can play with anyone who is on the same Wi-Fi network as you quite easily (tell them to visit agar.io/?ip=*your_ip:443*).

To get your ip address, on Windows, go to Start and search for and open cmd. Enter the `ipconfig` command to see your ip address.

[image: IPv4 Address....192.168.1.138]
<sub>(source: [the-computer-problems-guru.com](http://www.the-computer-problems-guru.com/images/computer-network-troubleshooting-ipconfig.jpg))</sub>

In the above example, you would share the link http://agar.io/?ip=192.168.1.138:443 with your friends, if that's the computer the server is running on.

Again, if you'd like to play with people on your same network, ask for elaboration and I will edit this answer.

---

And, if you'd like to share your game with the world (more risky, leaves you exposed to atacks) you can set up [port forwarding](https://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for) for your router and share your router's ip address and the game server's port on any forum you want.

[image: port forwarding diagram]

Honestly, the only way you might find someone else's private server online is by constantly watching agar.io forums and youtube channels.

Comment: While this looks like a good tutorial on how to set up your own server, this does not answer the question.

Comment: I interpreted the question as "How can I play on private servers?" because it's an easier way for the OP to accomplish what they want. And anyway, I have answered their question (How to *find* private server?), albeit right at the end of my post. I don't think my answer warrants a downvote.